# Is there some way to get the Message-Id from PHPMailer at the moment of sending the e-mail?

Tags: php, phpmailer, php-8.1

With PHPMailer, when you do `->send()`, it appears to not send any kind of "information" back except true/false: https://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer-PHPMailer-PHPMailer.html#method_send

I'm trying to get the "Message-Id" immediately back from the server when I send the e-mail. I need this in order to enter into my database to track the outgoing e-mails.

Yes, I insert the records into my database when I fetch the actually sent e-mails from the IMAP server, but I need to know what the Message-Id is so that I can verify automatically that it has been sent and whatnot, and not have to always look in my "sent" folder of my e-mail client to make sure it was actually sent (and thus fetched as a "sent" e-mail).

If this doesn't make sense, then at least know that I need to "track" it, but PHPMailer doesn't appear to send back any kind of information unless there is an error.

How do I get the Message-Id immediately when sending an e-mail with PHPMailer?

Comment: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/2650

Comment: @CodeSpirit Hmm... When I try `->getSMTPInstance()->getLastTransactionID()`, it just returns a boolean false. And this is for Gmail. But I noticed that it was not in the list of "patterns" hardcoded into PHPMailer. Which I find odd to say the least. But how would I figure it out on my own? As in, what exactly am I supposed to look for to regexp out?

Comment: Note the subtle but important difference between _queued to be sent_, which happens when you call the send() method, and _actually sent_, which may or may not happen some arbitrary unspecified time later. I.e., getting a true back doesn't mean the message was successfully sent, it means it was queued -- it may yet fail. If you need to track individual messages, you're probably best off adding your own unique id via a custom header in the message. You can generate this, and write it to the database, before calling send().

Comment: What Alex said. If there is not a Message-ID header in the message the MTA will automatically add one, and you will not be able to get this from the server aside from whatever nebulous, server-specific behaviour is putting it in your 'Sent' folder.

Answer (score 3):

The mechanism in [this issue](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/2650) is an internal identifier used by the receiving mail server, and is **unrelated** to the message ID. It's useful to know when looking at mail server logs, as usually every interaction with a client will be tagged with that ID, from initial connection through to delivery, which is not the case with the actual message ID.

You will find the actual message ID in `$mail->lastMessageID`, and I recommend retrieving it via [`$mail->getLastMessageID()`](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/src/PHPMailer.php#L1322), but only after you have actually sent the message. i.e. if you have not yet called `send()` or `preSend()`, it may not be there.

You can inject a message ID of your own choosing by setting the `MessageID` property directly, though it will be ignored if it's not valid according to [RFC 5322 section 3.6.4](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322#section-3.6.4).

There is no need to invent a new header for this.

Comment: Sadly, it just gives me empty strings. :/ The whole things seems extremely fragile and unreliable.

Comment: Show your code so we can see what you’re doing